# VBA closes another workbook when I only say 1

Tags: vba, excel

I have come across a strange glitch in a code that I found online. if I have two different spreadsheets open, one with this code in it and another that may well have no macros at all, and i leave that one alone for the specified time (as is the time I allow for in the macro) then the spreadsheet that has the macro in closes on me and then after the given time, the other spreadsheet closes too. Why does this happen?

Module 1:

```
Dim DownTime As Date

Sub SetTimer()
    DownTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DownTime, _
      Procedure:="ShutDown", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub ShutDown()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call ExampleToSaveWorkbook
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
End Sub

Sub ExampleToSaveWorkbook()
    'Saving the Workbook
    bnam = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    filenm = "S:\Economics\GTAA\dailyPM\excelfiles\backups\" & bnam
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filenm
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call SetTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call StopTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
  ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Call StopTimer
    Call SetTimer
End Sub
```

Why is it closing more than the 1 workbook which has the macro?

Comment: You are calling shutdown from the application object so if you only have 1 instance of Excel active with two workbooks open then calling shutdown closes both workbooks and exits excel.

Comment: @Sorceri Thank you for your help, but it's not just 2 workbooks with 1 instance. I have 1 instance with 4 or 5 workbooks, but it just closes 2 and then stops

Answer (score 0):

The `Shutdown` sub calls `ExampleToSaveWorkbook` which closes the active workbook.
The remainder of the `Shutdown` then proceeds to close the `ThisWorkBook` object.